# XAML build error on VB.NET project with controls from external DLL

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, xaml, controls

I'm trying to migrate a WPF Application based on C# to identical project but based writed in VB.NET.

I have some problem with XAML Window.

The Window have some reference from external dll controls. For example:

```
<Window x:Class="Window1"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:menus="clr-namespace:My.Frame.UI.WPF;assembly=My.Frame.UI.WPF.Menus">

    <DockPanel
           LastChildFill="True">

        <StackPanel
           DockPanel.Dock="Top"
           Style="{DynamicResource ToolbarStackPanel}">
           <menus:MenuFullMaintenance />
           <TextBox Name="Test02"/>
        </StackPanel>

    </DockPanel>

</Window>
```

if I build solution with this xaml, it's works correctly. But, if I write:

```
<menus:MenuFullMaintenance Name="Test01" />
```

I have this error message:
"Error 8 Type 'My.Frame.UI.WPF.MenuFullMaintenance' is not defined. (Window1.g.vb)"

The "Name" property raise this exception...why? How can fix it?

Comment: I solve. The problem was the root namespace of project...now I leave it empty and the project works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve. The problem was the root namespace on project properties.

Now I leave it empty and the application works correctly.